# How can I disable the use of bold fonts when editing code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, themes

I don't want Eclipse to display any keyword in bold. I've browsed through a lot of options in the Preferences window, but could not find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This depends on the type of file you're editing.   For example, in Java:

Window menu -> Preferences -> Jave -> Editor -> Syntax Colouring -> Java (in the "Element" box) -> Keywords excluding 'return' -> Uncheck bold

Similarly for "Keyword 'return'".

Look at the preview to check everything you want is no longer bold.

Comment: For C++, it's almost exactly the same procedure.  But you have to uncheck bold for a dozen or so different things.  Too bad there's not a single option to disable bold across the board.