# Disabling bold and italic fonts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fonts

Can you disable bold and italic fonts in Eclipse, without changing them one by one as explained in [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051980/how-can-i-disable-the-use-of-bold-fonts-when-editing-code-in-eclipse)?  Editing a configuration file with search/replace would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration file which you can edit but the changed values are stored in this file in your workspace:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
```

You can change the fonts as you like in eclipse (I think there are just a few bold and italic ones) and then transfer this file to other workspaces.

Comment: Actually, the involved file is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs`, while `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs` contains the font.  Thank you.